# How can I use $out operator after $inwind in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection `myCol` with many document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b730470c3190b97c4dab0"),
    "key1" : [ 
               {el:"El1"},
               {el:"El2"}
             ]
}
```

and I want to use the aggregation operator `$unwind` to obtain 2 separate documents, 1 for single element array and after I should save the aggregation result in a new collection.

If I use this query all works:

```
db.myCol.aggregate([{$unwind:"$key1"}])
```

but when I try to use $out operator to save the result, MongoDB returns an error!

Query: `db.myCol.aggregate([{$unwind:"$key1"},{$out:"$newMyCol"}])`

Error:

```
 QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Can't $out to special collection: $newMyCol",
        "code" : 17385,
        "codeName" : "Location17385"
    }
```

The `$unwind` operator creates 2 documents with the same `_id`, is this the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: 1) Collection name should not start with the `$` sign. 2) ***The $unwind operator creates 2 documents with the same _id, is this the problem? Yess***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a dollar sign in a new collection name. When you fix that you'll get another error that your `_id` values are duplicated (because of `$unwind`) so you can unset the old ones using `$project` and MongoDB will generate new values:

```
db.col.aggregate([{$unwind:"$key1"}, { $project: { _id: 0 } }, {$out:"newMyCol"}])
```